# merge of two image coming always top and bottom.but i want side by side in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, canvas

I have two images that I want to merge into one and show side by side (right and left). I've searched in websites and have gotten the below code, but it always is coming top and bottom only.

i think This occurs due to the extra code I added to make both images the same size.

my code:

```
if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) { 
width = c.getWidth(); 
height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight(); 
} else { 
width = s.getWidth(); 
height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight(); 
}
cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cs); 
canvas.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null); 
canvas.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth(), 0f , null);
```

and also I am using this code for make both image as same size

```
 Rect dest1 = new Rect(0, 0, width, height / 2); // left,top,right,bottom    
 canvas.drawBitmap(c, null, dest1, null);
 Rect dest2 = new Rect(0, height / 2, width, height); // left,top,right,bottom    
canvas.drawBitmap(s, null, dest2, null);
```

Comment: That does not seem to be valid code. What is the deal with `if{` on the first line? What is the condition?

Comment: @Daniel L. i updated that if condition.Can you please check now

Comment: Sure, I just don't type that fast, but I was producing an answer ;-). Should work, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

add customdrawable.xml in drawable folder

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
   <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image1" android:gravity="left"/>
 </item>
 <item>
   <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image2" android:gravity="right"/>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

use as @drawable/customdrawable.

[Example Link](http://www.fantageek.com/1265/android-xml-drawables-tips-and-tricks-part-4-layerdrawable/)

[LayeredDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList.)

If you requirement suites, you can use this.

Comment: sorry i can't able to follow you.Can you please tell little bit more

Comment: kindly check the links. I guess u need one mentioned in example link.

Answer (score 0):

1. Well, the first `if{` is not valid code, I assume you want some condition there to distinguish between side-by-side and above-below?
2. The `if` code seems identical to the `else` code (since they have the same width), you probably want to add the widths instead.

Overall, you probably want something like:

```
if(sideBySide)
   cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight() + s.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
else
   cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(c.getWidth() + s.getWidth(), s.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cs); 
canvas.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null); 

if(sideBySide)
   canvas.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth(), 0f , null);
else
   canvas.drawBitmap(s, 0, c.getHeight() , null);
```

Comment: Thanx for your quick response. I am using  your code (above mentioned) but now also i am getting top and bottom combination of image only. Waiting for your responce

Comment: did you try debugging it? Are you actually trying it with two image sets such that the `if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth())` condition does not always yield the same result?

Comment: Ah, it suddenly came to me: you made your images the same size by hand, `if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth())` will always return false. Try passing a boleaan variable like I did with `sideBySide`.

Comment: Sorry for late response. But now also same error happen

Comment: Well, it should not. My guess is that you are doing something wrong, somewhere else in the code not shown above. My advice would be to either put a few breakpoints and debug of make this into a function and build a unit test.

Comment: i am checked by using breakpoints also. But i can't understand whats a probelm. Can you tell one thing  (may be its a problem of my device)i am not sure i am checking by using Samsung galaxy tab 2. A waiting for your  responce

Comment: I think you are not following what I mean by debug and breakpoint?? If so, you should be able to see the value of your variables as the program runs. In particular, the condition for your IF clause.